# how can I increment a variable with the next value of a column

Tags: oracle

I have a function that have this code

```
for i in cursor
loop
variavel1=i.id
  while i.id=variavel1
   loop
    ---- do someting
    --- incriment variavel1 with next i.id
   end loop;

end loop;
```

I need to increment the variavel1 with the next id that i have in the i (object that have the date from the cursor).

Comment: why would `i.id` change inside the while loop _at all_? I sense a endless loop or some evil sideffects on `i`  incrmenting the `variavel1` by +1 might go into an i.id that is no longer there (row deleted with that id) and is missing. Please provide some more information about what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: i need to incriment the id because i need concatenet string for all same id. so the variavel1 have to set the id of the next row for even interation.

Comment: What you've said so far doesn't really make much sense I'm afraid. If you edit the question to explain what you actually need to achieve - preferably with sample data and expected results - we might be able to help you, but this approach is probably going down the wrong path. It kind of sounds like you really want to be doing aggregation (listagg) in the cursor query but at this point we can only guess...

Answer (score 1):

If concatenation is everything you need, you can use pure sql:

```
select id, listagg(text) within group (order by text) as list
    from (
        select 1 id, 'abc' text from dual union all
        select 1 id, 'def' text from dual union all
        select 1 id, 'ghi' text from dual union all
        select 3 id, 'jkl' text from dual union all
        select 7 id, 'mno' text from dual union all
        select 7 id, 'pqr' text from dual)
    group by id;
```

Other possibility, like in this PLSQL block:

```
declare
    cursor crsr is 
        select 1 id, 'abc' text from dual union all
        select 1 id, 'def' text from dual union all
        select 1 id, 'ghi' text from dual union all
        select 3 id, 'jkl' text from dual union all
        select 7 id, 'mno' text from dual union all
        select 7 id, 'pqr' text from dual;

    variavel1 number;
    variavel2 varchar2(1000);

begin
    for i in crsr loop
        if variavel1 is null or variavel1 <> i.id then
            if variavel1 is not null then
                dbms_output.put_line(variavel1||' - '||variavel2);
            end if;
            variavel1 := i.id;
            variavel2 := i.text;
        else
            variavel2 := variavel2 || i.text;
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(variavel1||' - '||variavel2);

end;
```

You can also define simple type as table of objects (id, text) and in loop add items to variable of this type.

```
declare
    type tob is record (id number, text varchar2(1000));
    type ttb is table of tob;

    variavel2 ttb := ttb();

    cursor crsr is 
        select 1 id, 'abc' text from dual union all
        select 1 id, 'def' text from dual union all
        select 1 id, 'ghi' text from dual union all
        select 3 id, 'jkl' text from dual union all
        select 7 id, 'mno' text from dual union all
        select 7 id, 'pqr' text from dual;

begin
    for i in crsr loop
        if variavel2.count = 0 or variavel2(variavel2.count).id <> i.id then
            variavel2.extend();
            variavel2(variavel2.count).id := i.id;
        end if;
        variavel2(variavel2.count).text := variavel2(variavel2.count).text||i.text;
    end loop;

    -- now we have array of values
    for x in 1..variavel2.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(variavel2(x).id||' - '||variavel2(x).text);
    end loop;

end;
```

I assumed that id is not nullable, if it is you need minor changes. Output for all solutions is:

```
    ID LIST
------ --------------
     1 abcdefghi
     3 jkl
     7 mnopqr
```

Answer (score 0):

open cursor;
   FETCH cursor INTO cursor_result;
   WHILE cursor %found
   loop
    variavel1=cursor_result.id
    WHILE( variavel1=cursor_result.id AND cursor %found)
      LOOP
        ---dO SOMITHING----
        FETCH cursor INTO cursor_result; ----PASS TO NEXT VALUE
      END LOOP;
   end loop;